# mysql comparing two columns per rows in one table

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
program   budget  jan_2 feb_2 mar_2 apr_2 jan_3 feb_3 mar_3 apr_3  
supplies  100000  10    0     0     0     0      0     0     0
equipment 300000  0     15    0     0     0     100000 0     0
```

I want to check if `jan_2 ,feb_2,mar_2,apr_2,jan_3,feb3,mar_3,apr_3` is empty or not  per program also after checking I want to compare if both dates example `jan_2` and `jan_3` are both empty or not. Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the final output you want to get, there are 0s in your expamples, shouldn't those be nulls since you mention them as empty?

Comment: if for example jan_2 and jan_3 are both not empty i will display 0

Comment: if jan_2 is not empty  and jan_3 is empty i will display the budget

Comment: or maybe check if its greater than 0 or equal to 0

Comment: Only jan_2 and jan_3 matter?

Comment: all the dates matter jan_2 and jan_3 is just an example i want to compare them all

Comment: Fix your broken table design. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: "if for example jan_2 and jan_3 are both not empty i will display 0 " you mean if they are BOTH EMPTY?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your description, your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT t.program,
       t.budget
  FROM <table_name> t,
       (SELECT SUM(jan_2+feb_2+mar_2+apr_2+jan_3+feb_3+mar_3+apr_3) totals,
               program prog
          FROM <table_name>) sums
 WHERE t.program = sums.prog
   AND sums.totals > 0
   AND t.jan_2 != 0
   AND t.jan_3 != 0;
```